# Convert X509Certificate to byte (getEncoded)

Tags: java, cryptography, x509certificate

I currently have this code here but it gives me NullPointerException on line 16.

```
byte[] frame = loadCertificate("GasClient").getEncoded();
```

If I comment out that line, then everything is fine - and even if I leave that line there, the code still prints out the certificate. Is there another solution to send the certificate between client and server? I tried with toString as well but that gave me the same error.

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class test {
    public static X509Certificate newCert;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        loadCertificate("GasClient");
        byte[] frame = loadCertificate("GasClient").getEncoded();
    }

    public static X509Certificate loadCertificate(String alias) {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            char[] password = "GasClient".toCharArray();

            try (InputStream keyStoreData = new FileInputStream(alias + "KeyStore.jks")) {
                keyStore.load(keyStoreData, password);
            }

            Key key = keyStore.getKey("Certificate-Authority", password);
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) key;
            System.out.println("Private Key: " + privateKey);
            java.security.cert.Certificate[] certs = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);

            X509Certificate newCert = (X509Certificate) certs[0];
            System.out.println(newCert);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newCert;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `e.printStackTrace()` into `throw new RuntimeException(e)` - then what happens?

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk Seems to compile fine on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem caused by variable shadowing. In the class you have the static field:

```
public static X509Certificate newCert;
```

However, in the try block you have the following line:

```
X509Certificate newCert = (X509Certificate) certs[0];
```

The `newCert` in the try block is not the same as the `newCert` defined at the class level. The `newCert` in the try block effectively hides or *shadows* the `newCert` declared at the class level.Then you exit the try block causing the `newCert` defined therein to go out of scope. Then you `return newCert`, but that `newCert` is the static class field one. It is initialized to null conceptually at class load time and you never change it, so when you return it you get null.

It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do here with the class design, but I'll assume you're a Java beginner and just struggling to learn the basics. There are two easy fixes. The first is to leave off the declaration inside the try block. So replace the above line with

```
newCert = (X509Certificate) certs[0];
```

The second is to get rid of the class field altogether and just return `newCert` from within the try block. Alternatively, you can declare `newCert` just above and outside of the try block and have a single point of exit.

Good class design is of course a larger and more fundamental topic, and I have not addressed it in this answer. I have simply suggested some quick fixes.

Thanks to Maarten Bodewes for leading me to the bug.

Comment: Ah I see my problem now. Thank you for pointing out them out very effectively, and thank you Maarten Bodewes for helping me out too.